# Unable to capture image using the Raspberry Pi Camera Python

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, camera, raspicam

The `raspistill -o image.jpg` command successfully captures images. But when I try capturing from a **really** simple Python script, I get an error. The script is

```
from picamera import PiCamera

cam = PiCamera()
cam.capture('image.jpg')
cam.close()
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/CamTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    camera.capture('image.jpg')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1423, in capture
    'Timed out waiting for capture to end')
picamera.exc.PiCameraRuntimeError: Timed out waiting for capture to end
```

What am I missing here? Need help.

[OS: Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ | picamera v1.13 | Raspberry Pi Camera Rev 2.1]

Comment: Are you sure there's not a bit more to your script? I'd expect that to fail with `NameError` given you're initializing `cam` but trying to execute a method on `camera`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Typing mistake. But, still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: After hours of digging and trial-and-error I have some insight about the issue. Using `cam.('image.jpg', use_video_port=True)` I'm able to acquire somewhat "**grainy**" looking image. This is because images taken via **still port** by `raspistill` undergoes a _strong noise reduction algorithm_ i.e. appear as higher quality compared to the **video port** Refer to http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fov.html#the-still-port. I think the error is related to **Encoding** as indicated by `pycamera/camera.py line 1423` @DaveJones

Comment: It might not be relevant but I'm running raspbian 4.9.41-v7+, the 2017-09-07 release on raspberrypi.org. My pi isn't on a network where it can get updates. I can't reproduce the error, the image is captured fine. Do you have a spare card to test the older version?

Comment: I could try this older version but where do I download it from? Seems the official site only provides the latest versions. And I'm guessing you are using the `Desktop` not the `Lite` one(?). @Craig

Comment: Hi, Yes it is the desktop version from  https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ . I was assuming the difference in version was mine has never seen the internet to get any updates.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying - been rather busy the last few days. I've tried to reproduce this with the exact same hardware and software versions - but to no avail. However, one thing does spring to mind. Can you try manually setting the resolution and framerate when initializing the camera? i.e. use `cam = PiCamera(resolution='1024x768', framerate=30)` for example? If that works for still port captures then I've got an idea what's going on ...

Comment: Its okay. I appreciate that you could manage to reply. @DaveJones
So, setting the `resolution` and `framerate` didn't help all. By the way, the syntax is `cam = PiCamera(resolution=(1024x768), framerate=30)`. But hear this, I just played with the `sensor_mode` parameter leaving the rest at defaults and the code runs smoothly for all values (inclusive) from **1** to **7** _except_ **2** and **3**. And the output image of 6 looks somewhat colors inverted or shifted. I guess it could somehow be related to [this](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/fov.html#camera-modes) Explanations??

Comment: + I mean `sensor_mode` equals to **2** and **3** gives the `'Timed out waiting for capture to end')
picamera.exc.PiCameraRuntimeError: Timed out waiting for capture to end` error. Any explanations?

Comment: Actually the syntax `resolution='1024x768'` or `resolution=(1024, 768)` ought to work (`resolution=(1024x768)` should be a syntax error in Python). The fact sensor modes 2 and 3 fail isn't too surprising: those are the [two image-capture modes](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html#sensor-modes) which still captures temporarily mode-switch to. Still that doesn't explain why it times out in picamera, but not raspistill (both treat the camera almost equally at the MMAL level).

Comment: How long does it take to timeout? I think the capture timeout in 1.13 is 60 seconds so I'm guessing you're waiting quite a while for the script to fail?

Comment: Could the syntax be related to Python version? I was on version 3.x. Nevertheless, I was able to get the `sensor_mode=2` to work by setting `framerate=15`. But couldn't do the same  for `sensor_mode=3`. And `sensor_mode=6` is **_really bad_**. Exactly, the `CAMERA_TIMEOUT=60` meaning 60 seconds before the timeout error appears.

Comment: I ran the `raspistill` with `-v` (verbose) argument and it output the default settings (if I'm not wrong). Could it have something to do with the error? Say, `picamera` can not initialize properly while `raspistill` could and thus the `timeout` error. (I get that `sensor_mode` 3 is a duplicate of 2 but expected them to work as I changed the `framerate`)

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly reproduce your problem (i had the  "Out of resources (other than memory)" error), but I still think your code lacks a crucial part : closing the camera after use.

So your code may work, but only one time : after that, the camera ressource will be locked, until reboot.

Adding a simple line may be enough for your minimal exemple :

```
from picamera import PiCamera
cam = PiCamera()
cam.capture('image.jpg')
cam.close()
```

For a real world code, you may want to use one of these syntax, that close camera even on unexpected error :

```
camera = PiCamera()
try:
    # do something with the camera
    pass
finally:
    camera.close()
```

or

```
with PiCamera() as camera:
    # do something with the camera
    pass
```

References taken from : https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_camera.html

Comment: Well, Its not working either. Even if it was the case I should get at least one image. `'Timed out waiting for capture to end')
picamera.exc.PiCameraRuntimeError: Timed out waiting for capture to end` error exists as before. @Technico.top

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from the PiCamera documentation. https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html

```
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.start_preview()
# Camera warm-up time
sleep(2)
camera.capture('foo.jpg')
```

The camera need time to adjust to the light level.

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer:

```
camera.capture('image.jpg', use_video_port=True)
```